# Join table in SQL doesn't return that I want

Tags: sql, postgresql

I havetwo table like this
[Table:customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IngrZ.png)
[Table:orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkr4X.png)
and want to display like
[join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfHnH.png)

I've tried

```
select 
concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as customer_name,
COUNT(o.customer_id) as total_orders,
sum(o.amount) as total_amount_order
from customers c
join orders o on c.id = o.customer_id  
where o.amount >= 500
group by o.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name, o.amount
```

but it's just returned only David Robinson data. What's wrong with my query? Any advice? Thanks

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

The `WHERE` clause is executed *before* the `GROUP BY` clause, so it's filtering out every purchase except Mr. Robinson's very expensive monitor *before* the aggregate sum.

I suspect you want to filter for `SUM(o.amount) >= 500`, but you can't put that in the `WHERE` clause because they're executed before the aggregate is done.

You need to use a `HAVING` clause, which is the same as a `WHERE` but executed after the aggregation, allowing you to do `HAVING SUM(o.amount) >= 500`.

I would show you the updated query, but I have a feeling this is homework. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I've tried add having  sum(o.amount) >= 500 after group by but doesn't work too

Comment: Is it still in a `WHERE` clause or is it in a `HAVING` clause?

The syntactic ordering of the clauses is irrelevant, it's the keywords which matters.

EDIT: I see you state "add having", that's extremely surprising, did you forget to remove the old `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score -1):

please try this

```
select 
concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as customer_name,
COUNT(o.customer_id) as total_orders,
sum(o.amount) as total_amount_order
from customers c
join orders o on c.id = o.customer_id   
group by o.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name
having  sum(o.amount) >= 500
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work, it's return same data as my query that I tried

Comment: you can try again


select 
concat(c.first_name, ' ', c.last_name) as customer_name,
COUNT(o.customer_id) as total_orders,
sum(o.amount) as total_amount_order
from customers c
join orders o on c.id = o.customer_id   
group by o.customer_id, c.first_name, c.last_name 
having  sum(o.amount) >= 500

Comment: Need to remove amount column in group by also. Then sum(amount) works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).